# Thread safe copy files from a folder to another

Tags: c#, .net, thread-safety

I want to do a programm that copy files from one folder to another and divided this in subfolders like YYYY/MM/DD. Now I've done this and with the watcher I will do this in the background (so every time a new file is created it will be copied)

How to do all this thread safe, so that the program can wait for 5 seconds until the new file is created and just after that to copy it ? My boss told me to do it with System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue.

```
public static void Main()   
{
    Run();
}

[PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
public static void Run()
{

    FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
    watcher.Path = @"C:\tmp";

    watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;

    watcher.Filter = "*.png";

    watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnCreated);

    watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

    Console.WriteLine("Press \'q\' to quit the sample.");
    while (Console.Read() != 'q') ;
}

private static void OnCreated(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{       
    Console.WriteLine("File: " + e.FullPath + " " + e.ChangeType);

    string fileName = "*.png";
    string sourcePath = @"C:\tmp";



    foreach (var file in new DirectoryInfo(sourcePath).GetFiles(fileName))
    {
        try
        {
            string dt = file.CreationTime.Day.ToString();
            string mn = file.CreationTime.Month.ToString();
            string yr = file.CreationTime.Year.ToString();

            var targetFolderName = String.Format(@"U:\{0:}\{1:}\{2:}", yr, mn, dt);
            var dir = Directory.CreateDirectory(targetFolderName);
            file.CopyTo(Path.Combine(dir.FullName, file.Name), true);
         }
         catch { }

     }
 }
```

Comment: What problems are you hitting with your current implementation? I assume the directory you're watching is an in-box with files arriving in it somehow? The main issue you'll face is knowning when the file has been fully copied in, and probably the best way to know that is when you can get an exclusive lock on it. When you can it's safe to copy.

Comment: What does "waiting five seconds" have to do with thread-safety?

Comment: stuartd , I'm a beginner with C#. Adam Benson you're right.